Create Service Report API callout from Apex - Bad request
I am trying to call Service Report creation using this link -
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.field_service_dev.meta/field_service_dev/fsl_dev_code_samples_sr.htm
Now I am getting  a 400 Bad request. Any help would be really helpful.
Code -
String woId = '0WO1l0000027aTMGAY';
List<ContentDocumentLink> contentDocumentLinks = [SELECT Id,ContentDocumentId, LinkedEntityId FROM ContentDocumentLink WHERE LinkedEntityId =: woId AND ContentDocument.Title LIKE 'Signature-%'];

System.debug('content document links -->' + contentDocumentLinks);
if (contentDocumentLinks == null || contentDocumentLinks.isEmpty())  {
    // TODO throw exception
}
List<Id> contentDocumentIds = new List<Id>();
for (ContentDocumentLink link : contentDocumentLinks) {
    contentDocumentIds.add(link.ContentDocumentId);
}

// To generate FSR with a blob signature
List<ContentVersion> version = [SELECT Id, VersionData FROM ContentVersion WHERE ContentDocumentId =: contentDocumentIds[0]];
String base64String = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(version[0].VersionData);
System.debug('content version data -->' + base64String);
System.debug('version -->' + version[0]);
// Create HTTP request
HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
request.setEndpoint('callout:FSLEH_CreateServiceReport/services/data/v41.0/actions/standard/createServiceReport');
request.setMethod('POST');
request.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
// Set the body as a JSON object
request.setBody('{"inputs" : [ {"entityId" : "' + woId + '","signatures" : [{"data":"' + base64String + '","contentType":"image/png","name":"Customer Signature","signatureType":"Customer","place":"San Francisco","signedBy":"John Doe","signedDate":"Thu Jul 13 22:34:43 GMT 2017"}],"templateId" : "0SL2p000000KzIkGAK"} ]}');
Http http = new Http();
System.debug(request.getBody());
HttpResponse response = http.send(request);
// Parse the JSON response
if (response.getStatusCode() != 201) {
    System.debug('The status code returned was not expected: ' +
                 response.getStatusCode() + ' ' + response.getStatus());
} else {
    System.debug(response.getBody());
}

Request body -
{
    "inputs": [{
        "entityId": "0WO1l0000027aTMGAY",
        "signatures": [{
            "data": "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",
            "contentType": "image/png",
            "name": "Customer Signature",
            "signatureType": "Default",
            "place": "San Francisco",
            "signedBy": "John Doe",
            "signedDate": "2024-06-05 12:00:00"
        }],
        "templateId": "0SL2p000000KzIkGAK"
    }]
}

Reponse received - [Status=Bad Request, StatusCode=400]
Response message - Unsupported action type: CREATE_SERVICE_REPORT"
Any help would be helpful

Check if this may help you. -https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=002232056&type=1

Thanks @TusharJadav. This may be the reason. Do you know if there is some easy way to identify these special characters and remove from header?
